# Nougat 7.1.2 debug issue

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, android-7.1-nougat

I recently enrolled my Pixel XL for Android Beta program. After the update to Nougat 7.1.2 my device is not detected properly in Android Studio Linux.

I get something like this in AVD monitor

```
HT6A70201284 [null]
```

But it was working on my windows desktop, I tried it on other linux devices and got the same issue. I came across a post mentioning about the driver support, so I updated my SDK to Android O preview, but it had no use.

Another strange behavior is when I turn of the debug mode in phone, it gets detected by my linux system, other posts state the same driver issues, but I am not able to figure out exactly which driver and from where I am supposed to install.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve it? I'm annoyed of this since couple of months.

Comment: @WindRider there is no permanent solution that I could find. I just change the connection mode to file transfer after connecting phone to laptop and it works fine then

Comment: I do the same plus another change to Transfer Photos (PTP). Without these 2 changes it doesn't work. Let's hope it will be fixed in O.

Comment: It definitely does not work on my Nexus 6P. What happens between you clicking "select USB configuration" and transferring files? My phone already had that option selected anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just a simple solution (Working on Nexus 5X, 7.1.2),

1. Developer options
2. Select USB configurations
3. Choose MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)

**OR**

If notification panel shows "USB charging this device"

1. Tap on it and just select "Transfer files"
2. Device detected.

Comment: I have to make not one but 2 arbitrary changes of the USB setting to make it work. So annoying.

Comment: Works with Nexus 6p, 7.1.2 too

Comment: Worked on Pixel 7.1.2 too

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if anyone else faced this issue, but after trying several stuffs, the problem seems to be solved **temporarily**.

Generally I use my device in charging mode while developing the apps, but after the update Android studio detects the device in **Data Transfer Mode only**, somehow, USB mode charging has some bugs in preview release and couldn't be detected by Android Studio.